# Php concatenate a string into field generated by Yii2

Tags: php, yii, yii2

I have the code to show the image (Yii2). $brand is an object, logo is a field of this object

```
<?= $form->field($brand, 'logo')->fileInput(['accept' => $acceptFileTypesInput]) ?>
```

After that, 'logo' will have value **'assets/uploads/logos/-4a47a0db6e.png'** ==> wrong path

I want to concatenate **Url::to('@web/')** before the value of 'logo' ==> **/app/backend/web/assets/uploads/logos/-4a47a0db6e.png**

How can I do it?

Comment: You want to append `@web` to `$acceptFileTypesInput`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to pass `value` key into options array:

```
<?= $form->field($brand, 'logo')->fileInput(
    [
        'accept' => $acceptFileTypesInput, 
        'value' => Url::to('@web/') . $brand->logo
    ]
) ?>
```